# DNS sub domain delegation failed (PDNS)

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm trying to delegate a subdomain from my power DNS server to some slaves.
I'm able to delegate the parent domain without any issues.  But when I try to delegate the a subdomain the transfer fails with this error:

"AXFR of domain 'www.exmaple.com' failed: not authoritative"

I can delegate 'example.com' to the exact same servers without issues.

Any idea?  This is power DNS version 3.1

Comment: Are you actually using `example.com` or is that to sanitize your question? Because the server is talking about `exmaple.com` instead

Comment: For the record: don't type error messages from memory.  Copy and paste them verbatim.  If you need to anonymize something, use search and replace to do it so that everything is consistent.

Comment: example.com is not the real domain name...  So yeah I made a typo, but the question is the same

Comment: Have you already delegated the parent?  If so the subdomain should have already been transferred.

Comment: Yes, the parent domain delegated without an issue.  So your saying that if I delegate the parent, any subdomain should be transferred along with the parent?